# Android SQL Database File not Appearing

Tags: javascript, android, sql

I'm working on an app for class that will be using a SQL database to keep track of distances and continually update them. I've never coded in java before or implemented a SQL database so I've run into some issues. Right now I'm trying to load my database with initial values (0) but the database file won't pop up in the device monitor, please help!

```js
package tamu.thecaddyapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonDriver, buttonFouriron, buttonFiveiron, buttonSixiron, buttonSeveniron, buttonEightiron, buttonNineiron, buttonPW, buttonFiftysix, buttonSW, buttonSixty;
    DataHandler helper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonDriver = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_DRIVER);
        buttonFouriron = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_4IRON);
        buttonFiveiron = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_5IRON);
        buttonSixiron = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_6IRON);
        buttonSeveniron = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_7IRON);
        buttonEightiron = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_8IRON);
        buttonNineiron = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_9IRON);
        buttonPW = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_PW);
        buttonSW = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_SW);
        buttonFiftysix = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_56DEG);
        buttonSixty = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_60DEG);
    }

    public void buttonDriver(View view) {
    }

    public void buttonFouriron(View view) {
    }

    public void buttonFiveiron(View view) {
    }

    public void buttonSixiron(View view) {
    }

    public void buttonSeveniron(View view) {
    }

    public void buttonEightiron(View view) {
    }

    public void buttonNineiron(View view) {
    }

    public void buttonPW(View view) {
    }

    public void buttonSW(View view) {
    }

    public void buttonFiftysix(View view) {
    }

    public void buttonSixty(View view) {
    }
}
```

```js
package tamu.thecaddyapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Owner on 11/12/2017.
 */

public class DataHandler {
    public static final String _ID = "_ID";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "SHOT_AVERAGES";
    public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME = "thecaddyappdb";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID + "TEXT NOT NULL"+ ") VALUES(150)";


    DataBaseHelper dbhelper;
    Context ctx;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DataHandler(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        dbhelper = new DataBaseHelper(ctx);
    }

    private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DataBaseHelper(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx, DATA_BASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DataHandler open(){
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        dbhelper.close();
    }

    public long insertData(int recalDist){
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        String clubName = "Driver";
        content.put(_ID, clubName);
        content.put(_ID, recalDist);
        return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, content);
    }

}
```

Additionally, I worked on this for awhile, so these files are a lot different than some of the stuff I've had, really just experimenting but not completely sure what's wrong, this code I was going for one column with values and will later implement the additional columns after I know a database file is being created.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the SQl file not showing in Android monitor, please ensure that you have your device API 22 or below. It doesn't work properly for API's above 22.

Comment: I've run it on API 22, still no luck

Comment: Where have you created a database in the main activity?